# How to leverage compiler-generated copy/move ctors when using unique_ptr as a data member?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, unique-ptr, deep-copy

Say I have a class with a `unique_ptr` data member, and I want the class to support copying, by deep-cloning the object the smart pointer is pointing at:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() { cout << "Bar::ctor " << this << '\n'; }
    ~Bar() { cout << "~Bar" << this << '\n'; }
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> clone() const { 
        auto p = std::make_unique<Bar>(*this); 
        cout << "Bar::clone() " << this << " to " << p << '\n';
        return p;
    }
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const & other) : p_{other.p_->clone()} { 
        cout << "Foo::copy-ctor " << p_ << ", other.p_ " << other.p_ << '\n';
    }
    Foo(Foo && other) : p_{std::move(other.p_)} {
        cout << "Foo::move-ctor " << p_ << ", other.p_ " << other.p_ << '\n';
    }
    Foo & operator=(Foo const & other) { 
        cout << "Foo::copy-assign " << p_ << ", other._p " << other.p_ << '\n';
        p_ = other.p_->clone(); return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator=(Foo && other) { 
        cout << "Foo::move-assign " << p_ << '\n';
        p_ = std::move(other.p_); return *this; 
    }

    void store(std::unique_ptr<Bar> p) {
        cout << "Foo::store() " << p << '\n';
        p_ = std::move(p);
    }

public:  // so we can print out p_ later
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> p_;
};

std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar() {
    return std::make_unique<Bar>();
}

int main() {
    Foo f;

    auto b = bar();
    cout << "b " << b << '\n';

    f.store(std::move(b));

    cout << "copy" << '\n';
    auto g {f};
    cout << "assign" << '\n';
    Foo h;
    h = f;
    cout << "move" << '\n';
    auto i = std::move(f);

    cout << "f.p_ " << f.p_ << '\n';
    cout << "g.p_ " << g.p_ << '\n';
    cout << "h.p_ " << h.p_ << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qjf8MoKsE

Output:

```
Bar::ctor 0x2314eb0
b 0x2314eb0
Foo::store() 0x2314eb0
copy
Bar::clone() 0x2314eb0 to 0x2315ee0
Foo::copy-ctor 0x2315ee0, other.p_ 0x2314eb0
assign
Foo::copy-assign 0, other._p 0x2314eb0
Bar::clone() 0x2314eb0 to 0x2315f00
move
Foo::move-ctor 0x2314eb0, other.p_ 0
f.p_ 0
g.p_ 0x2315ee0
h.p_ 0x2315f00
~Bar0x2314eb0
~Bar0x2315f00
~Bar0x2315ee0
```

It's a bit verbose but the point is that `= default;` doesn't work because of the `unique_ptr` data member and its deleted copy-constructor, so I have to manually define these functions to obtain the deep-copy semantics that I seek.

For a single `unique_ptr` data member, this isn't too bad. But if I add additional data members to the `Foo` class, it seems to me that I will have to explicitly copy/assign them in each of the four copy/move ctors/assignment operators, because the default member functions have not been generated.

This makes me wonder if there's a standard-library wrapper for `unique_ptr` that enables automatic deep-copy, as well as maintaining things like `const` correctness, that would allow me to reduce `Foo` to something like:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const & other) = default;
    Foo(Foo && other) = default;
    Foo & operator=(Foo const & other) = default;
    Foo & operator=(Foo && other) = default;

    // ...

public:
    DeepCopyUniquePtr p_;  // what is this?
    int a;
    float b; 
    // lots...
    char z;
};
```

Thereby falling back on the default copy/move ctors and assignment operators.

I also found that when I have multiple `unique_ptr` data members, these functions can also get messy quickly.

Comment: No, there's no such "wrapper" in the C++ library. But it's not a big deal to write one yourself.

Comment: Long story short: no, there is not, but writing one's own decorators should not be that hard. As for const-correctness you may have a look at [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) but again, it's trivial enough to be written while the coffee's getting ready ;)

Comment: You can look for keywords as "deep_ptr", "clone_ptr", or "value_ptr" to get some implementations.

Comment: You can still make the move members `=default`. What you need define is the copy versions. And the `clone` member is not actually required, unless there are special design considerations. `p_{std::make_unique<Bar>(*other.p_)}` does the deep copy. Then you can copy/move combo to define copy assignment:`return (*this)=Foo{other};`; move-assign the copy-constructed version. Or you can unify the assignments in one by-value assignment with copy/swap idiom.

Comment: @Red.Wave good point on `clone` - it's actually a hang-over from `Bar` being a derived class in my real code, so it's there as (what would be) a virtual function to prevent slicing when copying `other.p_`, when `p_` is a pointer to the base class. I appreciate that this isn't shown in my example code and I probably should have removed it. Is that a valid example of the "special design considerations" you are alluding to?

Comment: @davidA if it's legacy, then it is there. As long as you can identify the actual type at compile time, using a such a virtual function doesn't help much. Using templates usually (not always, but most often) means the type is known at compile-time, unless some type-erasure design removes that information.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you could write your own decorator.

```cpp
template <typename Ptr>
struct Clonable
{
    Clonable() = default;

    Clonable(Ptr&& ptr) : p(std::move(ptr)) {}

    Clonable(Clonable const& other)
     : p{other.p->clone()}
    {}
    
    Clonable(Clonable&& other)
     : p{std::move(other.p)}
    {
        other.p = nullptr;
    }

    Clonable& operator=(Clonable const & other)
    {
        p = other.p->clone();
        return *this;
    }

    Clonable& operator=(Clonable&& other){
        p = std::move(other.p);
        other.p = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator*() {
        return *p;
    }

    auto operator*() const {
        return *p;
    }

    auto operator->() {
        return p.operator->();
    }

    auto operator->() const {
        return p.operator->();
    }

    Ptr p;
};

template <typename T>
using DeepCopyUniquePtr = Clonable<std::unique_ptr<T>>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eTqTEncfa

Comment: If you have c++20 you would probably want to constrain `Clonable` for pointer arithmetics and the `clone` member function using appropriate concepts.